# Firebase Was called with 1 argument. Expects none

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, canvas

I have tried different values of once() and then() but I seem to get a similar error. The current error message is:

"DataSnapshot.val failed: Was called with 1 argument. Expects none"

I am using firebase as my database and I'm trying to withdraw an encrypted image from it under the field of ('Canvas').
Here is my code

```js
//DECRYPT IMAGE
var decrtpt, img;
function decryptImg(){
  firebase.database().ref('Cords/' + img).on('value', function(snapshot){
    decrypt = snapshot.val('Canvas')
    console.log(decrypt);
  });
}
```

What do I need to do to fix this error. So that I can decrypt the string so I can use the image, many thanks :) I am using JavaScript just in case you did not know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`snapshot.val()` doesn't accept any argument.

If you attach an async callback to read the data at your `'Cords/' + img` reference, you can receive the data using `snapshot.val()`. If the data is an object and you want to get the value by key, you can do it like this:

```
function decryptImg(){
  firebase.database()
    .ref('Cords/' + img)
    .on('value', function(snapshot){
      const image = snapshot.val()
      console.log('Canvas: ' + image.Canvas)
  })
}
```

For more info check https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#node.js

Comment: Are you sure the `ref` is correct and there is data? `.val()` returns `null` when the `DataSnapshot` is empty (contains no data): https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#val